# Android Camera setJpegQuality ignored

Tags: java, android, camera

It seems that the setJpegQuality method of Camera.Parameters is ignored, at least on the devices I've tried it with (Nexus S, Galaxy S2).

Does it work for anyone else, or is this a known issue, or am I doing something wrong, or... ?

Code for setting parameters below.  jpeg quality 1 is very distinctive, so it's very easy to determine visually whether it's working... and it isn't!  Other parameters set here (e.g. sepia) work.

```
    camera = Camera.open();
    final Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setJpegQuality(1);
    parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    // Let's set a SEPIA effect, just to verify these parameters are working at all!
    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SEPIA);
    // I've seen this syntax too on the internet, presumably it's legacy.
    parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 1);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: Most probably this is device specific and I suggest trying an HTC, but ultimately many people have a Galaxy device.

Comment: What is the api level that you selected when you created this new project?

Comment: @CommonKnowledge I'm using API Level 8.

Comment: Try setting the quality "parameters.setJpegQuality(1);" higher to like 80+. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Does not work as far as I can tell, regardless of the value, but it's somewhat difficult to tell in the higher ranges (less degradation, larger image size).

Comment: Is there any error in the log?

Comment: The quality levels are maybe equal to the human eye, can you check the file size for different levels?

Comment: Did you find solution? I have the same problem on Philips Xenium W632, when on HTC wildfire all works fine

Answer (score 1):

Set all attributes of the picture:

```
parameters.setPreviewSize(854, 480);  // (h, w)
   parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
   parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 100);
   parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
   parameters.set("rotation", 90);
   mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
   mCamera.startPreview();
```